# With sed, delete only a certain matched address range

Tags: regex, linux, sed

The following text has 2 address ranges that will be matched
using `sed -n '/#/,/\$/p'`:

```
foo
#bar
foo
$
foobar
#foo
$bar
foobar
```

How can I delete a specific match only (1st, 2nd...)?
Below should be the output for deleting 2nd match only:

```
foo
#bar
foo
$
foobar
foobar
```

Comment: How are you running it to delete only the 2nd match?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to distinguish the Nth match of an address range. This would be easier in `awk` since you can increment a counter variable.

Comment: Your code doesn't delete the lines in a range, it keeps those lines and deletes the lines outside the range.

Comment: My code '/#/./\$/' was only to show there are 2 matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/#/{x;s/^/x/;x};/#/,/\$/{x;/^x{2}$/{x;d};x}' file
```

Set up a counter in the hold space and use it to determine which range to delete.

This has the added advantage of being able to delete a range of ranges e.g.

```
sed -E '/#/{x;s/^/x/;x};/#/,/\$/{x;/^x{2,3}$/{x;d};x}' file
```

This will delete the second and third ranges.

Comment: Wow! This works great. Could you explain how it works? I was beginning to believe that this couldn't be done in sed. You have spectacular knowledge of sed.

Comment: @Joshro the best way to see how it works is to use the debug option `--debug` i.e. `sed --debug -E '/#/{x;s/^/x/;x};/#/,/\$/{x;/^x{2}$/{x;d};x}' file`